# Base icon for a Qt application

Tags: qt, icons

My problem is simple.

How do I add an icon that appears in Windows Explorer ?

Not the specific window I want the whole application like the command prompt has the C:\ on the icon.

Is there any way I can do that without creating files and linking it to the .pro file ?

Can I change that base icon in the Qt Creator ?

If so, how ? If not how do I do it otherwise ?

Thank you

PS I have tried the other questions out there and none of them work at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicaly, on Windows, you have to create an .rc file for your icon and then add a line in you .pro file for it :

```
  RC_FILE = myapp.rc
```

All the details are available in Qt Documentation: [Setting the Application Icon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/appicon.html)

Answer (score 0):

**In Qt 4**, you need to create a .rc file like this:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myIcon.ico"
```

You should add this to your .pro file :

```
win32: RC_FILE += MyApp.rc
```

**In Qt 5** there is an automated process for setting an icon to the application executable file .

You can just add the following to the .pro file:

```
win32: RC_ICONS = myIcon.ico
```

Also store the .ico file in your application's source code directory.

Note that this is only for Windows. There are other ways to set application icon in Linux and Mac.